# Unable to tap on Allow button from popup

Tags: eclipse, appium, eclipse-oxygen

I have java developed application and when I start the application after the splash screen, it asks me calendar permission in popup but I am not able to tap on the allow button with the use of Appium. Please share if anyone has an idea.

I have only a resource id to use.

Resource id:- com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button

Comment: Add this capability..this will take care of all the App permission. capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);

Answer (score 0):

You can add `autoGrantPermissions` capability in your desired caps.

Below is the description from [appium docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) in case you want to understand more.

> **autoGrantPermissions**: Have Appium automatically determine which permissions your app requires and grant them to the app on install. Defaults to false. If `noReset` is true, this capability doesn't work.